# pthread_kill to a GCD-managed thread

Tags: macos, pthreads, grand-central-dispatch, darwin, mach

I am attempting to send a signal to a specific thread with `pthread_kill`. I use `pthread_from_mach_thread_np()` to get a handle and then use `pthread_kill` to send the signal.

This worked well in my other testing, but now I see that when attempting to signal a thread internally created by GCD, I get a return code of 45 from `pthread_kill`.

GCD API that spawned that thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0), ^{ ... });
```

Any reason this is happening?

—-

To add some further information, I am not attempting to kill threads. `pthread_kill()` is the standard POSIX API to send signals to threads. If a signal handler is installed, the thread’s context is switched with a trampoline to the handler.

While what I attempt to achieve using my signal handler can be achieved in better ways, this is not in question here. Even if for purely academic reasons, I would like to understand what is going on here internally.

Comment: 45 = `ENOTSUP`, i.e. "Operation not supported"

Comment: @Rob Yes, I saw that in the header. But the question is why; how are those threads different?

Comment: In [Compatibility with POSIX Threads](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW18) they explicitly warn that blocks "must not call" `pthread_kill`.

Comment: @Rob Interesting document thanks. However, I am not sure that is the reason. I am not calling `pthread_kill` from a block.

Comment: Blocks are just one example.  As it says, "In general, your application must not delete or mutate objects or data structures that it did not create."  You have no idea what code would receive the signal.

Comment: @Ssswift I absolutely do have idea, since I have installed the signal handler.

Comment: Leo: You installed the signal handler, but you can't know what other tasks might be running on that thread.  You can't even be sure that your own task is still running there, since GCD is allowed to move it to a different thread (even the main thread).

Comment: @Ssswift I am sorry, you misunderstand how signal handlers work. Tasks running on a thread are irrelevant.

Comment: Leo: I said essentially the same thing as @das did, below, in the answer you accepted (only without the link to the source code).  Please enlighten me.  What do you think I not understand?

Comment: Looking at the source of that link, the limitation is artificial, and to me, breaking POSIX. Signal handlers are meant to run regardless of what a thread is doing. I wanted insight into possibly differences of thread implementation, but instead got the answer there is no difference. For me, that is not a good reason enough to break POSIX, but this is what Apple has chosen. I have other options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `pthread_kill()` API is specifically disallowed on workqueue threads (the worker threads underlying GCD) and returns `ENOTSUP` for such threads.

This is primarily intended to prevent execution of arbitrary signal handlers in the context of code that may not expect it (since these threads are a shared resource used by many independent subsystems in a process), as well as to abstract away that execution context so that the system has the freedom to change it in the future.

You can see the details of how this is achieved in the [implementation](https://github.com/apple/darwin-libpthread/blob/master/src/pthread.c#L1348).

Answer (score 0):

That is a very bad idea. You don't own GCDs thread-pool, and you absolutely must not kill its threads out from under it.

The answer to your question is **DO NOT DO THAT UNDER ANY CIRCUMSTANCES**.

Comment: I am not trying to kill the threads. I have a signal handler installed and obtain backtrace addresses using that handler. It has already been suggested by Grep Parker to use mach API to achieve this without signals, but the question remains purely for academic reasons - how are those threads different. With all due respect, your answer is not an answer.